# What view-function to be used for repositioning view frame (to cover 20point status bad gap)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Lately Ive been working with moving my frame to make up for the 20point gap when the status bar is not showing in landscape mode. I have finally gotten what I want, yet there is one problem that kind of annoys me. Let me explain: First I was using a call in viewDidLoad to move the frame, but that doesn't do anything to the frame, because I suppose the frame gets drawn *after* viewDidLoad. So I tried placing my call in viewDidAppear. That works smoothly, but sadly the user "sees" the repositioning; you can watch the frame being replaced with the bare eye. So I was wondering if theres anything I can do to prevent this, any workarounds. (just for good explanation this call is to take care of view frame when the user updates/go to another view controller when already in landscape. I have other functions to take care of rotation; which obv works)

Any help appreciated. I tried to be as specific as possible.
Thanks!

Comment: You can use autolayout and set constraint to 'top layout guide', it will be in the bottom of the status bar when the status bar exist, and top of the view otherwise. no need to change frame

Comment: @oren how do i make a constraint specifically to that top layout guide. I normally do editor->pin view to superview, or use the pins inside IB, which constraints to the next element in that direction. Id still be plead with an answer, as issues like this has been bugging me before, where a change is made after view is appeared but won't work if done in viewdidload.

Comment: @oren at second thought, Im not sure what you suggested can be to a parent view like that. The view does not take constraints/cannot be applied. I have another project where that problem with the 20point doesn't exist, tbh i dk why, but its not constrained in any way to top layout guide like that either (just a note, pls take my comment above in regard).

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to confuse you as I don't really understand your view hierarchy. But anyway, in the nib, you can control-drag from the view to its parent (the viewController's view) and set - 'Top Space to Top Layout Guide'. In any case, if you don't really know autolayout, I recommend you to do some tutorial, it makes things much easier to set the constraints in the nib, instead of changing the frame. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: i am using auto-layout^^ thx anyway, will play around with it another time. I have searched for other post where they try to get rid of the game, none of them has the answer to "just" pin to top layout guide.